# ¿Porqué esta consulta si me funciona si la ejecuto en phpmyadmin pero si la pongo en php no?

Tags: php

Tengo una tabla con el siguiente valor en el campo razonsocial en uno de los registros ---> "DIF CDC N¬∞ 11 POLANCO". (sin las comillas)
La tabla tienen codificación UTF-8 UNICODE (utf-8), el campo razonsocial también tiene codificación utf8_general_ci

Ahora el código php que realizé para eliminar de la cadena el valor "¬∞" (Sin comillas) es el siguiente:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
include("conex.php");
$con = conectar();
$sql= utf8_encode("update prospectos set razonsocial =REPLACE(razonsocial, '¬∞', '')   ");  
mysql_query($sql) or die('error en la consulta '. mysql_error());
echo "Tabla modificada con éxito";
```

La consulta si la ejecuto en web no modificada el valor del registro, pero si la ejecuto en phpMyadmin si modifica el valor correctamente.

¿Alguna orientación de porqué no me funciona? Gracias

Comment: ¿Has comprobado con que charset te conectas a la base de datos en conex.php?  Y porque haces un utf8_encode de algo que aparentemente ya está bien escrito?  ¿Y que codificación tiene el archivo php donde esta el código?  Revisa todo eso a ver si ves alguna incoherencia

Comment: Lo puse por que si se lo quito, tampoco funciona y pensé que quizás así funcionaría correcto.

Comment: Que sepa la funcion de conectar no soporta opciones para indicar charset

Comment: No se, ahora me doy cuenta que estas usando `mysql_query` que está obsoleto desde la versión 5.5.0  de PHP.  Debes buscar donde tengas la funcion mysql_connect y usar esto [`mysql_set_charset`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-set-charset) para forzar la conexion con UTF8.

Comment: Al aplicar estos comandos ya funcionó, gracias

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro :-)  Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Al agregar estos comandos y eliminar las funciones utf8_encode ya funcionó!

```
include("conex.php");
$con = conectar();
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);
$conjunto_caracteres = mysql_client_encoding($con);
```